# Git commit not adding files, only blank lines

Tags: git, ubuntu

Working on Ubuntu 16.04. I have added a change to git. Git status is showing the change is ready to commit. However, when creating a commit, all that happens is 2 blank lines. Like so:

```
~/$ git commit


~/$
```

The response is the same no matter what commit flags I include. Afterwards, git status still shows the files as ready to commit. What am I missing here?

Comment: I know you said you've tried lots of commit flags, but what happened when you typed `git commit -m "message"`?

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing. 2 blank lines

Comment: What is the result of `git status`?

Comment: It shows the changes as added. Both before and after trying to commit

Comment: Try making a change, doing `git add -A` and then running `git commit -m "message"` and see what happens.

Comment: No change for that either

Comment: Have you recently set up some Git hooks?  In particular, have you set a pre-commit and/or commit-message hook?

Comment: No git hooks of any kind. There should not have been any modifications to the git settings in some time.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of experimentation, the problem was git hooks. Running commit with -n got things working again. Thanks to @torek for suggesting it. Not sure how they got there though.